# Mule HTTP Request: Error query-param with large string

Tags: php, rest, http, mule, mule-component

I am calling the REST (PHP) from Mule HTTP Request using query-param.

This works fine, with small params data!

But one of the params ("rest_data") is a content file (Base64 encoded). When the file content is large (> ~8K) the request faild. I think that params does not support large strings.

What should be the way to use **body** instead **query-param** on Mule in this case?

See the configuration file:

```
   <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="164.164.164.233" port="80" basePath="/crmtec/service/v4_1/rest.php" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
    </http:request-config>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP Documento">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="method" value="set_document_revisions"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="input_type" value="JSON"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="response_type" value="JSON"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="rest_data" value="#[flowVars.params.rest_data]"/>
        </http:request-builder>
        <http:success-status-code-validator values="0..599"/>
    </http:request>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is in the payload will be send in the body of the HTTP request, so you should add that rest_data to the payload with a `set-payload` component before the `http:request` component:

`<set-payload value="#[flowVars.params.rest_data**]"/>`

It's not a good practice to use query params for large data, that's why it fails.

Comment: I changed and did not work, neither with small file now. I am consumig PHP Rest (change not possible!) on Mule. Would need it to understand that the data ´rest_data´ no more in param but now stay on body?

Comment: If the REST API you are consuming requires to send that data as a query param, then there's not much you can do since that's how it was designed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this similar issue while calling GIS REST API. Try below code. For post request, you can the payload as MAP of all params. Well designed REST should be able to handle it -

```
<set-payload value='#[{'method':'set_document_revisions', 'input_type':'JSON', 'response_type':'JSON','rest_data':flowVars.params.rest_data}]' />
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP Documento">
        <http:success-status-code-validator values="0..599"/>
    </http:request>
```

Answer (score 0):

We should be using POST method instead of GET to send large data structures over HTTP

Answer (score 0):

When you query parameters are long, you would think about put the query string into the HTTP request body, set the request type to POST method instead of GET.

Here is a page list the limit of how many characters in a URL: https://boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

Remember that the query string (name/value pairs) get transformed in the URL of GET request

> `GET /something/?name1=value1&name2=value2 HTTP/1.1 Host: yourhost`
>
> `POST /something/ HTTP/1.1 Host: yourhost name1=value1&name2=value2`